# ログイン済みユーザーをTwitter連携させる際にコールバック後、サーバー側で既存ユーザーを探す方法を知りたい

Tags: twitter, oauth

### やりたいこと

ログイン済みのユーザーをTwitter連携させたい

### 構成

- フロント: React
- バック: Rails API

### 使用しているgem

- [omniauth-twitter](https://github.com/arunagw/omniauth-twitter)

### Railsでの認証で使用しているgem

- [devise_token_auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth)

### 想定するTwitter連携の挙動

1. 「twitter連携する」ボタンを押す
2. twitter用の認証画面表示される
3. ユーザーがtwitter認証情報入力する
4. 入力完了後、コールバックでサーバーのapiが呼ばれて連携が完了する

### 困っていること/知りたいこと

上記4番のコールバックにより、サーバー側のapiが呼ばれて

- DBに保存されている既存のユーザーを探す
- DBに保存されている既存のユーザーにtwitterから取得したデータを紐付ける

ことを想定しているのですが、DBに保存されている既存のユーザーを探すためのパラメータをどのように用意するか分からず困っています。

そもそも、ログイン済みユーザーをTwitterと連携するために使用するgemとして、omniauth-twitterはふさわしくないのかもと思ったりしていますが、よくわからず。。

どなたかアドバイスいただけると助かります。

Comment: 一般的には、OAuth2.0処理の結果得られたアクセストークンを伴ってユーザ情報取得エンドポイントへアクセスすれば良いかと思います。Twitter APIの場合は [`/2/users/me`](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/users/lookup/api-reference/get-users-me) が該当するのではないでしょうか。レスポンスに含まれる `id` がユーザー識別子のように読めます。 / もし何かライブラリやフレームワークを利用する想定であれば、そちらの情報も質問文中に記載した方が良いかと考えます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。使用しているライブラリを追記いたしました。

Comment: 「既存のユーザーを探す」というのがよくわからないんですが単にツイッター認証した本人のアカウント情報が知りたいってことですか？　それともログインしたユーザの権限を使って第３者のユーザ検索をしたいってことですか？

Comment: @chico ありがとうございます。どちらでもないです。「既存のユーザー」とは、すでにDBに登録されているユーザーのことを指していました。ツイッター認証した本人のアカウント情報をもとにDBに登録されているユーザーの情報を更新する、ようなことを想定していました。

Comment: ジェムの説明を見ると 4 で Rails のエンドポイントを呼ばせれば request.env['omniauth.auth'] の中に色々書かれてるらしいですね
Rails側のログイン認証の詳細をかかれていないのでこれ以上は回答できないですが
devise なら current_user.twitter_id = request.env['omniauth.auth'].id して current_user.save とかでいいのかな？

Answer (score 3):

すでにDBに登録されている、との事なので、

- 自サーバーにログインさせ、ユーザーを識別できるセッション情報をユーザーのブラウザに保存する（ログイン処理が有るなら既に実装済みのはず）
- Twitter 連携で Twitter のサーバーへ
- Twitter で認証後、コールバックで自サーバーに戻させ、最初に保存したセッション情報を参照する

でよいと思います。